# Problem with Data Segment Reigster in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a problem with Data Segment Register.
After compile and link my program, it's crashed after exit, so i was tried to debug it with ollyDbg.
And OllyDbg said to me that i have problem with reading memory "Access violation while reading".
So what i need to do, to run my program normally.
Code is here:

```
.486
.model flat
.stack 256
.data
string DB 8  dup (0), 0
alphabet DB 30h, 31h, 32h, 33h, 34h, 35h, 36h, 37h, 38h, 39h, 41h, 42h, 43h, 44h, 45h, 46h
number EQU 0ABCE9FEh 

.code
_main:
    mov eax, number
    mov ebx, eax

xor ecx, ecx
xor edx, edx
GETWORD:
    inc edx 
    shld ecx, ebx, 4
    push ecx
    mov edi, offset string
    mov esi, offset alphabet
    mov ecx, ebx
    mov ax, [esi + ecx]
    mov ecx, edx
    mov [esi + ecx], ax
    pop ecx
xor ecx, ecx
shld ebx, ecx, 4

cmp ebx, 0
jne GETWORD

mov ah, 04ch
int 21h
end _main
```

Comment: Flat memory model and you are calling a DOS interrupt? Seems like you have crossed a DOS program and a Windows program and ended up with something that likely won't run properly. Rather than using DOS interrupt to exist remove `mov ah, 04ch
int 21h` and make a call to [ExitProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess)

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question?  You aren't modifying `ds`.  Anyway, how are you building this into an executable?  Is this going into a 32-bit Windows executable?  If so, `int 21h` won't work, you'll need to call a Windows `exit` function, or return from `main` if you linked with CRT start files.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but if not then it's simply lacking a [mcve], so closing it for now.  If that's not the right dup target, [edit] your question with a [mcve] including how you're building and running your program.